# wysihtml5 text area resizing

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

I am using wysihtml5 editor, simple editor example

```
http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/examples/simple.html
```

Everything works fine, except I am trying to make the text area width and height resizeable.

If I switch to html view it works great. I want to allow the text area resize in normal text.

Comment: The solution was resizing the wysihtml5 editor creates.

Answer (score 3):

Once Editor loaded change css of Editor it self;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').css("resize", "both");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this easy solution working with wysihtml5-0.3.0.js

```
<style>
textarea { ... min-height:500px; }
</style>

<textarea><?php echo $doc2edit; ?></textarea>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  resizeEditor(); // resize iframe containing HTML tags
}
function getElementsByClass(node,searchClass,tag) {
  var classElements = new Array();
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag); 
  var elsLen = els.length;
  var pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+searchClass+"\\b");
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
   if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
       classElements[j] = els[i];
       j++;
  } } return classElements; 
}
function resizeEditor(){
  // resize elem with class 'wysihtml5-sandbox' 
  var el = getElementsByClass(document,'wysihtml5-sandbox','*');
  for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].style.height = (editor.composer.commands.doc.body.clientHeight+20)+"px";
  }
}
</script>
```

and in wysihtml5-0.3.0.js :

```
BOX_FORMATTING = [
 ...., "min-height"
```